# evalの妥当な使いどころ

Tags: common-lisp, lisp

`eval`は強力過ぎるのでできるだけ使うな、とは良くいわれることですが、では、妥当な使いどころはどういう場合でしょうか。

私が思い付く限りでは、`quote`の逆操作として`eval`を利用するのは妥当かなと思います。

```
(eval ''foo)
→ foo
```

リスト操作でも可能ではありますが、

```
(cadr ''foo)
→ foo
```

はちょっと気持ち悪いですし、妥当かなと。

他には、どういった例があるでしょうか。

Comment: 「quote外しがしたい」と思ってる場合、対象が`(quote X)`であることは分かってる(もしくは事前に`(eq (car data) 'quote)`で確かめてる)ので、それならcadrでいいんじゃないかという感覚です。コードとデータの世界の往来として見る場合、確かにevalとquoteは対っぽいんですが… マクロ中で実行時環境にアクセスしたい場合にevalすることはありますが特定の状況下でのハックみたいなものだしなあ。

Comment: 確かに、事前チェックの段階でリスト構造というのは分かっちゃっている感はありますね。特に (cadr '(quote foo)) と書くなら尚更そうかも。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

簡易的な言語処理系の実行器としての用途に使えるということを考えたことはありますね。

パース結果をＳ式として組み立てて、 (ちょっと複雑な言語なら間に意味解析なども狭んで) 適当な名前空間で eval すればそのまま言語処理系になります。

外部からの入力を eval するのはセキュリティ上の問題になりやすいとは言われていますが、パース (と場合によっては意味解析) の段階で正当性を検証済みならば問題になりませんし、有用な使い方だと思います。

Answer (score 3):

trivialですが、自前のreplを作る時。齊藤淳志さんの回答のサブセットとも言えます。

Answer (score 2):

コード中ではありませんが、『On Lisp』ではマクロのデバッグで`macroexpand-1`してもよくわからないとき、展開結果を`eval`してみるというケースが紹介されていました。

> Sometimes, though, the expansion will look fine and you'll want to evaluate it to see where the problems arise.
>   [...]
>   In the worst case you can set a variable to the list returned by macroexpand-1, then call eval on it:
>   *(7.4 Testing Macroexpansion)*

Answer (score 1):

外部から読み込んだS式に対する`eval`は妥当である（というより使えないと困る）と思います。

```
* (eval (read-from-string "(+ 1 2)"))

3
```